# EF6 Transaction rollback & concurrency issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions

Once I rollback my transaction and try again, it fails with **DbUpdateConcurrencyException**.

After looking at SQL profiler, I see that first time INSERT query is sent, as expected, while second time it tries to **update**, even though first one was rolled back?!

First query:

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[FiscalReceipt]([PurchaseTime], [ReceiptNumber], [Cash], [Card], [Bank])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4)
SELECT [FiscalReceiptID]
FROM [dbo].[FiscalReceipt]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [FiscalReceiptID] = scope_identity()',N'@0 datetime2(7),@1 int,@2 decimal(18,2),@3 decimal(18,2),@4 decimal(18,2)',@0='2016-02-08 15:05:43.9145089',@1=666,@2=1.70,@3=0,@4=0
```

Second query:

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].[FiscalReceipt]
SET [PurchaseTime] = @0, [Cash] = @1
WHERE ([FiscalReceiptID] = @2)
',N'@0 datetime2(7),@1 decimal(18,2),@2 int',@0='2016-02-08 15:12:11.8101261',@1=555.00,@2=2042
```

P.S. Shouldn't there be TM:Rollback or TM:Commit in the EventClass column in SQL Profiler table when something is commited?

C# Code:

**NOTE:** OutOfPaperException is intended to be ignored and transaction inside that scope is being commited on purpose. Changes should be rolled back on any other exception.

```
var transaction = DatabaseContext.Database.BeginTransaction();

            try
            {
                // Commented for debugging
                //IFiscalPrinter fPrinter = DeviceManager.GetFiscalPrinter();
                //var lastReceiptNumber = fPrinter.GetLastReceiptNumber();

                // false data for debugging
                var lastReceiptNumber = 666;
                Receipt.ReceiptNumber = lastReceiptNumber++;
                Receipt.PurchaseTime = DateTime.Now;

                DatabaseContext.SaveChanges();

                //fPrinter.PrintFiscalReceipt(Receipt);

                // Exception for debugging purpose
                if (Receipt.Cash < 500)
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                transaction.Commit();

                Close();
            }
            catch (OutOfPaperException)
            {
                if (transaction != null)
                {
                    transaction.Commit();
                    Close();
                }

                MessageBoxService.ShowMessage("Promenite papir pre sledećeg štampanja!", "Nema više papira!", MessageButton.OK, MessageIcon.Warning);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // I added this but this doesn't help
                Receipt.PurchaseTime = new DateTime();
                Receipt.ReceiptNumber = 0;
                //Receipt.FiscalReceiptID = 0; <- I'm not allowed to do this

                if (transaction != null)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                }

                MessageBoxService.ShowMessage(ex.Message, "Greška!", MessageButton.OK, MessageIcon.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (transaction != null)
                {
                    transaction.Dispose();
                }
            }
```

DatabaseContext lifetime is equal to ViewModel's lifetime.

**EDIT:** Changing appropriate entry states to EntryState.Added results in successful operation, but it feels so dirty. Shouldn't entries remain in Added state on transaction rollback/fail?

**EDIT2:** After running this code:

```
using (MetalShopDB ctx = new MetalShopDB())
using (var transaction = ctx.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    var receipt = new FiscalReceipt()
    {
        ReceiptNumber = 555,
        PurchaseTime = DateTime.Now,
        Cash = 100
    };

    ctx.FiscalReceipts.Add(receipt);

    Console.WriteLine("Has changes " + ctx.ChangeTracker.HasChanges());
    Console.WriteLine(ctx.Entry(receipt).State);

    ctx.SaveChanges();

    Console.WriteLine("Saved changes");

    Console.WriteLine("Has changes " + ctx.ChangeTracker.HasChanges());
    Console.WriteLine(ctx.Entry(receipt).State);

    transaction.Rollback();

    Console.WriteLine("Rolled back");

    Console.WriteLine("Has changes " + ctx.ChangeTracker.HasChanges());
    Console.WriteLine(ctx.Entry(receipt).State);
}
```

I get this output, which I find really strange, because one would expect context to be in sync with db, so when you rollback, context should follow up with the changes.

```
Has changes True
Added
Saved changes
Has changes False
Unchanged
Rolled back
Has changes False
Unchanged
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*For your EDIT2*

When SaveChanges methods is called, if no error is found when saving (which is the case since you rollback after), the **ObjectContext.AcceptAllChanges()** methods is invoked which accept changes and populate primary keys, foreign keys and change entry state.

The rollback only rollback the transaction and not on the object context / change tracker.

It's to late at this point to call SaveChanges again since entities are already populated with database information even if you did a rollback.

*Original Question*

You throw an error (for debugging) after the SaveChanges has been **successfully completed**

```
if (Receipt.Cash < 500)
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

So by following the previous logic, the AcceptAllChanges is already invoked.

**EDIT**

You can control the AcceptAllChanges by saving using the ObjectContext

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter) ctx).ObjectContext;
objectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave);

transaction.Commmit();
objectContext.AcceptAllChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan. Would this be the right way to handle transactions in EF6 so that Context reflects on rollbacks?

Comment: Yes and not, people don't have normally this kind of issue with transaction because they commit after the SaveChanges happened. In your case, you throw an error which doesn't have anything related with the SaveChanges action and here is the problem. If you can, you should make your validation before the "SaveChanges" but is probably unlikely your case.

Comment: The problem is I must not print the receipt unless it's saved as well. This seems like a logical way to go, since DB transaction is reversable, printing is not.

Comment: So using the SaveChanges from the object context and controlling the AcceptAllChanges is the way to go I believe ;)